# Getting values from a queryset getting TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable

Tags: django, python-3.x

I know this is a very simple question but I am hitting `TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable` on everything I am trying. I need to get the `ratings`  for the `item`. How do I get it

```
>>> for item in order_items:
...     if item.reviewed_items.exists():
...             print( item.reviewed_items.values())
... 
<QuerySet [{'
id': 1, 
'review_from_id': 5, 
'review_for_id': 1,
'ratings': '8'}]>
>>>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try  [dict comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) as,

```
for item in order_items:
    if item.reviewed_items.exists():
        print({data['id']: data['ratings'] for data in list(item.reviewed_items.values())})
```

**UPDATE**
Use [**`values_list()`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#values-list) method as,

```
for item in order_items:
    if item.reviewed_items.exists():
        print(item.reviewed_items.values_list('ratings', flat=True))
```

Comment: awesome I got `{1: '8'}` just trying to isolate '8'

Comment: I know this is silly but how do I get the answer to just me 8